# Unknown cmake command "append_list_if"

Tags: cmake, llvm

[In this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQti6.png) of what my terminal looks like right now, the red is the command I executed, and the yellow is the error that I got that seems to be throwing everything off.

I'm trying to build llvm for a project I'm supposed to run/test, and I'm getting this error that the command "append_list_if" is unknown. This is all sort of new to me, so I'm curious as to how to fix this.

That is also why I've attached a photo of the terminal in case there are other things present in this picture that need to be fixed that I don't see.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to add missing details (see [mcve] ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: Especially: please read [no pictures of exceptions](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/) / [no pictures of code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode). Then use the [edit] link to replace screen shots of text with nicely formatted/indented text within your question.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such function in CMake. See [search results](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/search.html?q=append_list_if&check_keywords=yes&area=default) for `append_list_if` in documentation. I may suppose that you use the snippet from another project. In this case, you can search for the function there.

I found the similar one at [github.com/llvm-mirror](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/compiler-rt/blob/master/cmake/Modules/CompilerRTUtils.cmake):

```
# Appends value to all lists in ARGN, if the condition is true.
macro(append_list_if condition value)
if(${condition})
    foreach(list ${ARGN})
    list(APPEND ${list} ${value})
    endforeach()
endif()
endmacro()
```

You can try it.